# Process.Start doesn't open URL on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008, process.start

I am using the following code to successfully open the requested URL in the system default browser on Windows 8.1:

```
public static void OpenUrlInDefaultBrowser(string url)
{
    var httpKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"http\shell\open\command");

    if (httpKey == null || httpKey.GetValue(string.Empty) == null) 
        return;

    var cmd = httpKey.GetValue(string.Empty) as string;

    if (cmd != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cmd.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] splitStr;
                string fileName;
                string args;
                if (cmd.Substring(0, 1) == "\"")
                {
                    splitStr = cmd.Split(new[] { "\" " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    fileName = splitStr[0] + "\"";
                    args = cmd.Substring(splitStr[0].Length + 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    splitStr = cmd.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    fileName = splitStr[0];
                    args = cmd.Substring(splitStr[0].Length + 1);
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName, args.Replace("%1", url));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
    httpKey.Close();
}
```

However, on my Windows Server 2008 R2 VM, this same code opens Internet Explorer (the default on that machine), but will only load the URL `res://iesetup.dll/SoftAdmin.htm`. IE is set to Enhanced Security Mode OFF. Chrome works as expected on this machine.

Simply invoking `Process.Start(url)` also fails to open the requested URL.

When I execute the following from the "Run..." menu, it works as expected: `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://example.com`. The same goes for `start-process http://example.com` in PowerShell.

[image]

Comment: can you run your application in administrator mode? Might have something to do with permissions

Comment: Good thought, but I'm running as Administrator.

Comment: Disable the IE Security mode warnings by making some registry changes,

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/248c4794-8af9-43ac-9524-6ae69f4c93d4/changeremove-first-home-page-warning-when-starting-ie8-caution-internet-explorer-enhanced?forum=windowsserver2008r2rds

Comment: @Ryios These suggested registry changes had no effect.

Comment: Did you read the post where he talks about changing it for the 64 bit and 32 bit versions?  And did you log off and back on after making the changes?

Comment: Yes I made all those registry changes, and then logged off. Still no effect. I hate Microsoft.

Comment: Is User Access Control on?  How are you running as administrator?  Your console app might run as an administrator but if UAC is on any processes it starts will be running in user mode (affected by UAC).  I am not able to reproduce your problem on the same Operating System with the ENhanced Security turned off, but I have UAC disabled.

Comment: I have UAC disabled. I am right-clicking the executable and running as Administrator.

Comment: Also, this doesn't solve the url not opening but that page is what opens because it is the default page that IE opens with which you can change in tools -> options.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try simply calling   `Process.Start("http://your_website_here");` ? It's not like you need to specify browser, if you want to run hyperlinks on default one.

@davidsbro - yes, i wouldn't have made it as answer otherwise :)
@mark - try http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/28/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-in-windows-server-2012/ - that has something to do with server security settings and not application.

Comment: This should probably be a comment since it's asking a question; however, I know you don't have enough rep for that or else I would've downvoted this.

Comment: Perhaps it could be reworded as an answer

Comment: @Vytautas Yes, that's the first thing I tried. `Process.Start(url)` has the same effect of opening IE directly to `res://iesetup.dll/SoftAdmin.htm`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a modified version of your above method to start ie with command line options and is a little more detailed in figuring out which process to start.

Also, try changing the Process.Start calls in the code I'm posting to use a specific user and password.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenUrlInBrowser("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        }

        public static string GetDefaultBrowserCommand()
        {
            string command = null;
            var httpKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"http\shell\open\command");
            if (httpKey == null)
                throw new Exception("No default browser is configured!");
            else
            {
                command = (string)httpKey.GetValue("", "iexplore.exe");
                int exeIndex = command.ToLower().IndexOf(".exe");
                if (exeIndex > -1)
                {
                    int endOfCommand = command.IndexOf('"', exeIndex);
                    int startOfCommand = command.LastIndexOf('"', exeIndex - 1);
                    if (startOfCommand > -1 && endOfCommand > -1)
                    {
                        command = command.Substring(startOfCommand + 1, endOfCommand - 1);
                        return command;
                    }
                    else
                        throw new Exception("Error: Default browser is not set in the registry correctly!");
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("The default browser registry setting does not specify an executable!");
            }
        }

        public static void OpenUrlInBrowser(string url)
        {
            string browserCommand = GetDefaultBrowserCommand();
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(browserCommand);
            ProcessStartInfo psi = null;
            if (!fi.Exists)            
                Console.WriteLine("The default browser specified in the registry does not physical exist on disk!");
            else
            {
                string commandFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName).ToLower();
                switch (commandFileName)
                {
                    case "iexplore":
                        psi = new ProcessStartInfo(browserCommand, string.Concat("\"", url, "\"", " ", "-extoff -new"));                            
                        break;
                    default:
                        psi = new ProcessStartInfo(browserCommand, string.Concat("\"", url, "\""));
                        break;
                }
            }
            psi.UseShellExecute = true; //<- have to set this to make runas work
            psi.Verb = "runas"; //<- instructs the process to runas administrator, which will give the user a UAC prompt if UAC is turned on.
            Process.Start(psi);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code, from within my WPF app, takes me to this URL: `about:NoAdd-ons`. From the command line as a standalone executable it works fine though.

Comment: It's basically ignoring the %1 argument, and opening whatever is set in Internet Options -> General -> Home Page

Comment: It should be passing the url as an argument, I didn't test non iexplorer execution might be a bug. I'll check.

Comment: Yeah, I ran this in a console app on windows server 2008 r2 and it works fine for me, opens the url I tell it to with Iexplore.exe as the default, or chrome, or firefox.

Comment: Again, it works fine as a console app, but that same code from within my WPF app is what's misbehaving.

Comment: I updated my code to enable shell execute and runas,  give it a whirl now. In fact just using shell execute alone might do it for you, that operates on a higher level as if the user had started the process themselves in the explorer.exe (Windows GUI).  Also the code I wrote, was so that I could tell Internet Explorer to run without extensions enabled incase that was an issue.  If shell execute works you could go back to using just ProcessStartInfo and Process.Start.

Comment: Yeah it does, if the browser isn't iexplore, it builds the process start command without the -noext and -new arguments.  Which may or may not be relevant.  All the code here, including mine, works on my 2008 r2 VM, why it won't work for you is what's baffling, something to do with the WPF app I think which is why I thought shellexecute might do it.

Comment: `launchCommand` is assigned to at the end, but never used as a parameter.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I changed it when I added ProcessStartInfo, not needed anymore.